# Beautify array paths with variable keys

Tags: php, arrays

**How to turn this:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.0 - Classic
    [1] => 1.0 - Legends of Azeroth
    [2] => 01. Main Theme.mp3
)
```

**Into this:**

```
1.0 - Classic/1.0 - Legends of Azeroth/01. Main Theme.mp3
```

**Note:**

```
There may be more than 3 keys.
```

Comment: `echo implode("/", $arr);` OR a simple php book, because this is basic! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [**`implode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) (a/k/a [**`join`**](http://php.net/function.join)):

```
implode('/', $theArray);
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)